# Replace a DATE format string from a string in VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to replace the dates from my string.

```
Dim s As String = 
"06-26-19  06:09PM       <DIR>          10
07-25-19  01:40PM       <DIR>          13
07-02-19  06:08PM       <DIR>          14
07-24-19  05:49PM       <DIR>          15
06-21-19  08:00PM       <DIR>          17"
```

Desired result:

```
10 13 14 15 17
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing multiple characters from a single string in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906035/replacing-multiple-characters-from-a-single-string-in-vb)

Comment: @Athira no its not since the dates are random

Comment: @JammyDodger I am now looking to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014295/searching-for-a-specific-format-in-a-string

Comment: But it has values from 0-9

Comment: yap, numbers @Athira

Comment: You could `split` the string lines into an array, then take the `right` two characters from each array element to achieve the described output.

Comment: With the `=` at the end of the Dim statement, this doesn't look like VB6 to me. You might want to double-check which of the many versions of VB you're actually using.

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates a basic way to get the desired string using the Split command to break down the text into lines and then each line into columns.

I created a new project with a Command1 button to test the code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim s As String

    s = "06-26-19  06:09PM       <DIR>          10" & vbCrLf & _
        "07-25-19  01:40PM       <DIR>          13" & vbCrLf & _
        "07-02-19  06:08PM       <DIR>          14" & vbCrLf & _
        "07-24-19  05:49PM       <DIR>          15" & vbCrLf & _
        "06-21-19  08:00PM       <DIR>          17"

    MsgBox GetData(s)

End Sub
```

In this example, it recreates the string you posted as a string variable (s) broken down into lines using vbCrLf, make sure that's the same line break you have in your data and replace

```
Function GetData(ByVal p_sDirectoryListing As String) As String
    Dim arrLines As Variant
    Dim arrColumns As Variant
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim sReturn As String

    ' Split string into array, using CRLF as delimiter
    arrLines = Split(p_sDirectoryListing, vbCrLf)

    ' Initialize return value
    sReturn = ""

    For iCounter = 0 To UBound(arrLines)

        ' Break line down into columns
        arrColumns = Split(arrLines(iCounter), " ")

        ' Append space after previous value, you can change this to any delimiter you like
        If sReturn <> "" Then sReturn = sReturn & " "

        ' Append last column to return string
        sReturn = sReturn & arrColumns(UBound(arrColumns))

    Next

    GetData = sReturn

End Function
```